# Match the top of the characters and the bottom baseline of the font

Tags: html, css, baseline

Do you know of a reliable way to have borders matching the baseline of the font and the top of the characters?

I'm not sure it's very clear as I lack the words to explain this precisely, so here is an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwjLf. This is what I've been able to achieve messing with the line-height property until finding the best value:

```
line-height: 0.7em;
```

But I guess it's not a very clean or reliable way to do it.

Comment: I think you are using the most raliable way to do this, just make shure the `line-height` value matches the font-family you are usin.

Comment: There is no better way. CSS doen't know the height of the font. Finding the right line height with trial and error is the best way, although it might be a bit different on another platform, so make sure to take that into account.

Comment: Since you don’t even know which font family will effectively be used by the client, I’d advise against trying to “optimize” this for a specific font. Writing text onto a canvas and then have a little algorithm look at the pixels and try to determine it might work though.

Comment: Actually it seems this solution (line-height: 0.7em) works quite well with most fonts on my computer. I haven't tested it on other platforms or with more rare fonts though.